# Transparent Background of Matplotlib Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Matplotlib and Seaborn for some plotting purposes. I want plots that have a transparent background instead of a black-background. My code is

```py
plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.swarmplot(x='type',y='value', data=df, size=3.5, color='r', alpha=0.4)
sns.boxplot(x='type',y='value',data=df)
```

and the plot is
[image]

Now is there any style or technique using which I can have same background color of plot which I have for my cell, i.e background of my plot is Transparent.

Thanks